# reflexive arrow

Tags: arrows

```
$$ 
\begin{array}{c} 
\ovalbox{A} \\
\uparrow \downarrow \\
\ovalbox{B} \\
\uparrow \\
\ovalbox{C} 
\end{array} 
$$
```

(The `fancybox` package is used here, so that `\ovalbox{B}` appears as a capital B in a box with curved corners.)

This is a crude sort of picture of a simple directed graph, and although all I need is something simple like this, I also was to be able to show an arrow pointing from `\ovalbox{B}` to itself, set to the right of `\ovalbox{B}`.  How can I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).  Also, it's usually preferable to post a complete minimal document instead of a code fragment.

Comment: For looking up symbols, see [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol). However, like Alan, I would suggest using [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for this sort of thing. The second tutorial in the manual (`pgfmanual.pdf`) should contain everything you need. Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure the way you're doing this is ideal. I would suggest using the TikZ automata library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every state/.style={draw,rectangle, rounded corners},node distance=2em]
\node[state] (A) {A};
\node[state] (B) [below=  of A] {B};
\node[state] (C) [below= of B] {C};
\path[thick,-to] (A.-105) edge (B.105)
                 (B) edge (C)
                 (B.75) edge (A.-75)
                 (B) edge [loop right] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]